# Setting value of root node in repeat function on xforms

Tags: xml, xforms, xsltforms

I have an xforms (xsltforms) form containing a repeated list on the TEI `<placeName>` element. The repeat works fine, as does initializing the data for the `<placeName>` attributes, but I can't find a way to change the value of `<placeName>` on initialization. I'm guessing this is because it is the root node in the repeat, but I don't see why I can't change the value.

```
<xf:trigger>
  <xf:label>New place name</xf:label>
    <xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate">
      <xf:insert ref="instance('place')/listPlace/place/placeName" at="index('repeat')" position="after"/>
        <xf:setvalue ref="instance('place')/listPlace/place/placeName[last()]">placename</xf:setvalue>
        <xf:setvalue ref="instance('place')/listPlace/place/placeName[last()]/@type"/>
        <xf:setvalue ref="instance('place')/listPlace/place/placeName[last()]/@lang"/>
  </xf:action>
</xf:trigger>
```

Any ideas?
Cheers
Ralph

Comment: Could you please post a minimal testcase with the repeat control and a test instance?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me @AlainCouthures. It turns out that the issue was that i have to explicitly use the '.' self node as my input field in the repeat rather than using the node name/Xpath. I still don't understand why, but it solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my issue here was not with the initializing per se but with the display and update: the field to use for the root node of the repeat needed to be the '.' self node only and not either the node name or the Xpath. Not sure why this is, but it does solve the problem.